# Unpredictable behaviour in nested CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm unable to figure out why the control goes always to a statement irrespective of inside `CASE` condition.

A normal SQL statement works, but with my table it does not work.

```
--Not working--

SELECT
CASE WHEN [INTERNALDESCRIPTION] IS NOT NULL THEN --INTERNALDESCRIPTION IS A TEXT FIELD
    CASE WHEN 'INT' = 'INT' THEN  -- Or 'TEXT' = 'INT'
        REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),[INTERNALDESCRIPTION]  ) ,'''','') --should have come here
    ELSE 
        REPLACE( CONVERT(INT,[INTERNALDESCRIPTION]  ) ,'''',''  ) -- Always comes here no matter what condition
    END 
ELSE 
    'NULL' 
END 
FROM  DBO.RESOURCESTRINGMASTER WITH(NOLOCK)  WHERE 1=1

-------working--
DECLARE @VALUE1 AS varchar(max) = '1Test', @VALUE2 AS VARCHAR(MAX) =   '2'
SELECT 
CASE WHEN @VALUE1 IS NOT NULL THEN 
    CASE WHEN 'INT' = 'INT' THEN        
        REPLACE( CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),@VALUE1  ) ,'''','')
    ELSE 
        REPLACE( CONVERT(INT,@VALUE2  ) ,'''',''  ) 
    END 
ELSE 
    'NULL' 
END
```

And results in below error:

> Explicit conversion from data type text to int is not allowed.

Comment: I think he meant irrespective :)

Comment: *"Explicit conversion from data type text to int is not allowed."* ->  TRY_CAST(), TRY_PARSE() or TRY_CONVERT() ? See [Conversion Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/conversion-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: It is not running the statement, it is failing because it sees something illegal.

Comment: I wonder why here: `REPLACE( CONVERT(INT,[INTERNALDESCRIPTION] ) ,'''',''  )` you try to convert `[INTERNALDESCRIPTION]` to INT since you want to apply on it the REPLACE() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Explicit conversion from data type text to int is not allowed.

This error message seems pretty clear.  Why are you using a `text` data type?  It is deprecated.  To quote from the documentation:

> IMPORTANT! ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

So, your code on the real table is executing the `ELSE` condition, which causes it to fail.  In the code with constants,  `ELSE` condition is not failing.  Why is this?

I think the error is being caught in the *compilation* phase of the query.  The error does not occur in the second example, because SQL Server is short-circuiting the query, recognizing that the `ELSE` is not needed.  The code in the second example is simply not compiled.

I am pretty sure you would see the same behavior if you replaced the code with `1 / 0` (although the other part of the `case` expression would need to change as well for the types to be compatible).

Comment: The control always goes to `REPLACE( CONVERT(INT,[INTERNALDESCRIPTION]  ) ,'''',''  )` even if I swap their places :(

Comment: @John . . . It is not "control".  This is happening during the compilation phase.  The query is not valid, because it is attempting to do something that is not allowed.  The second query doesn't have this problem because the compiler is smart enough to know that the `case` condition is a constant, so it doesn't compile the second condition -- no compilation, no error.

Comment: You're right if I remove that line, the conditions are working fine. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not running the statement, it is failing because it sees something illegal.

If you want to see it on the other case change this line

```
DECLARE @VALUE1 AS varchar(max) = '1Test', @VALUE2 AS VARCHAR(MAX) =   '2'
```

to

```
DECLARE @VALUE1 AS TEXT = '1Test', @VALUE2 AS VARCHAR(MAX) =   '2'
```

You are comparing different test cases -- the first is not using VARCHAR

Comment: I've already tried that, I get this error `The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables`

Comment: The problem is the problem you can't cast TEXT to int

Comment: Yes that was the issue. I converted the TEXT to NVARCHAR, all is well now. Thank you.